# How to write firebase reference query with javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase database

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want result like

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using firebase with latest angular

How can I write this type of reference query in firebase so easily can get my expected results from database?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to query across multiple levels, which is not possible. The Firebase Database can only query a flat list of children, where the value you're filtering for is in a fixed path under each immediate child of the location you query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested